# rewriting a loop in numpy for faster execution

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am writing a function which accepts a numpy array `a` of length 200, and matrix `M` of size 200 x 200, and does the following operation :

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    x = a[i]
    for j in range(len(a)):
        y = a[j]
        z = M[i][j]
        d[i][j] = 2 * z/(y+x)
return d
```

How can I vectorize this piece of code to boost my runtime?

Comment: You have to specify the `shape` of `a` and `M`

Comment: please check the updated description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's ufuncs all have an [`outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html?highlight=outer#numpy.ufunc.outer) method to perform operations "cross-wise" on two arrays.  So to avoid most intermediate calculation and vectorize as far as possible:

```
def f(M, a):
    return 2 * M / np.add.outer(a, a)
```

---

**Answer for the old version of the question (left, because it's still useful)**:

For such things, I found it best to always work in steps, and try to find the right [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html?highlight=einsum#numpy.einsum) expression.

```
# the definition given in the original question,
# before the z / (y + x) update
def f0():
    d = np.empty((3,3))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        x = a[i]
        for j in range(len(a)):
            y = a[j]
            z = M[i][j]
            d[i][j] = 2 * x/(y+z)
    return d

# rewrite things inlined
def f1():
    d = np.empty((3,3))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            d[i, j] = 2 * a[i]/(a[j] + M[i, j])
    return d

# factor out broadcasting
def f2():
    d = np.empty((3,3))
    for i in range(len(a)):
        m = a + M[i, :]
        for j in range(len(a)):
            d[i,j] = 2 * a[i]/m[j]
    return d

# more broadcasting
def f3():
    d = np.empty((3,3))
    m = a + M
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            d[i,j] = 2 * a[i]/m[i,j]
    return d

# now turn loops into einsums
def f4():
    d = np.empty((3,3))
    m = 1/(a + M)
    d[:,:] = 2 * np.einsum('i,ij->ij', a, m)
    return d

# collect everything
def f5():
    return np.einsum('i,ij->ij', a, 2 / (a + M))
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! I compared outputs of  ```f5```  and my function, but the outputs weren't the same( I checked using np.allclose()).

Comment: That's interesting. It works for me on dummy inputs.

Comment: Can you inspect the actual differences by eye? Are your results completely off?

Comment: yeah, the max value in the 200 * 200 matrix for my solution is ~ 1.76, with the einsum operation its > 80000. I'm testing the functions on dummy data generated using `np.random.random()`

Comment: how are you testing with dummy inputs?

Comment: Just some 3 by 3 `arange` things :D I'll try it now with larger data.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/phipsgabler/c5953b2201b8141b5bf4b7ce1f66910d) prints `True`. Do you initialize `d` correctly in the comparison?

Comment: I goofed up in defining the expression for matrix `d`. It should be `d[i][j] = 2 * z/(x + y)` instead. That's why I'm getting a false on comparision.

Comment: See, that's why I removed those intermediate variables :D

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try to figure out the necessary expression from your example.

Comment: The new case is actually easier, wait a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
d = 2*numpy.atleast_2d(a).T/(a+M)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from numpy-vectorization using Numba would also a simple and performant method, to speed up code with loops.
**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",parallel=True)
def calc(a,M):
    d=np.empty((a.shape[0],a.shape[0]))
    for i in nb.prange(a.shape[0]):
        x = a[i]
        for j in range(a.shape[0]):
            y = a[j]
            z = M[i,j]
            d[i,j] = 2. * z/(y+x)
    return d
```

**Timings**

```
M=np.random.rand(200,200)
a=np.random.rand(200)

d=calc(a,M) #first call takes longer due to compilation overhead
%timeit d=calc(a,M)
#parallel=True there is only quite limited speedup because of the small problem (200x200)
#11 µs ± 51 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
#parallel=False
#21.2 µs ± 191 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

#pure numpy solution (hpaulj)
%timeit d = 2 * M/(a[:,None]+a[None,:])
#75.7 µs ± 386 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

#without compilation
#20.8 ms ± 500 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a pair of sample arrays (you should have provided these):

```
In [196]: a = np.arange(1,4); M = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)                                                       
In [197]: a                                                                                                          
Out[197]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [198]: M                                                                                                          
Out[198]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [199]: d = 2 * M/(a[:,None]+a[None,:])                                                                            
In [200]: d                                                                                                          
Out[200]: 
array([[1.        , 1.33333333, 1.5       ],
       [2.66666667, 2.5       , 2.4       ],
       [3.5       , 3.2       , 3.        ]])
```

The `a[None,:]` could be simplified to `a`, but I wanted to clarify the broadcasting use to calculate this outer product.  There are various tools in numpy for do this.  I like the `None` indexing because it is simple and idiomatic.

testing against your code (again, you should have provided such a result):

```
In [202]: def foo(a): 
     ...:     d = np.zeros((3,3)) 
     ...:     for i in range(len(a)): 
     ...:         x = a[i] 
     ...:         for j in range(len(a)): 
     ...:             y = a[j] 
     ...:             z = M[i][j] 
     ...:             d[i][j] = 2 * z/(y+x) 
     ...:     return d 
     ...:                                                                                                            
In [203]: foo(a)                                                                                                     
Out[203]: 
array([[1.        , 1.33333333, 1.5       ],
       [2.66666667, 2.5       , 2.4       ],
       [3.5       , 3.2       , 3.        ]])
```